# C++ equivalent of C# nested private classes

Tags: c#, c++

I am learning C++ coming from C#. In C#, there can be classes such as the following:

```
public abstract class BankAccount
{
  private BankAccount() {} // prevent third-party subclassing.
  private sealed class SavingsAccount : BankAccount { ... }
  private sealed class ChequingAccount : BankAccount { ... }
  public static BankAccount MakeSavingAccount() { ... }
  public static BankAccount MakeChequingAccount() { ... }
}
```

This way, consumers do not worry about the type of `BankAccount` and cannot nest their own subclasses.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in C++?

Comment: the keyword `final` might help you (C++11)

Comment: You are never going to completely align the semantics of two different languages. Also it might not make sense in the target language to do so. I recommend that you don't try to view C++ through C# glasses. Forget what you know about C# and learn C++ from scratch.

Comment: stick with c# and use the unsafe keyword. if you don't know what you are doing with c/c++ you can really open yourself up to bad security flaws.

Comment: @Galik: True, but you can do this with pretty standard C++ - nothing fancy.

Comment: I recommend against nested classes.  To see many issues related to nested class, search the web for "stackoverflow c++ nested".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'm a little bit wary of a design that couples the interface to the implementation and would prefer to have the subclasses and factories separate from the `BankAccount` interface but let's assume you want it that way.

Be careful with nested classes in C++, before C++11 they had no special access rights to the outer class, but you could achieve a similar thing with friend classes.

With C++11 we get the `final` specifier that allows us to prevent subclassing.

Here is the version using nested classes, using friend classes instead would be very similar:

```
#include <memory>

class BankAccount {
 private:
  class SavingsAccount;
  class ChequingAccount;
  BankAccount() = default;  // prevent third-party subclassing
 public:
  virtual ~BankAccount() {}
  static std::unique_ptr<BankAccount> makeSavingsAccount();
  static std::unique_ptr<BankAccount> makeChequingAccount();  
};

class BankAccount::SavingsAccount final : public BankAccount { };

class BankAccount::ChequingAccount final : public BankAccount { };

std::unique_ptr<BankAccount>
BankAccount::makeSavingsAccount() {
  return std::make_unique<SavingsAccount>();
}

std::unique_ptr<BankAccount>
BankAccount::makeChequingAccount() {
  return std::make_unique<ChequingAccount>();
}

int main() {
   auto savings = BankAccount::makeSavingsAccount();
   auto chequing = BankAccount::makeChequingAccount();
}
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a87aff76b4d7e05)</kbd>

The factory methods have to return a pointer, preferably a smart-pointer like `unique_ptr`. `unique_ptr` can be converted to `shared_ptr` if required.

Answer (score 0):

This is straight forward in C++:

```
class BankAccount
{
private:
    BankAccount(){}
    class SavingsAccount;
    class ChequingAccount;

public:
    static BankAccount MakeSavingAccount();
    static BankAccount MakeChequingAccount();
};

class BankAccount::SavingsAccount final : public BankAccount
{
};

class BankAccount::ChequingAccount final : public BankAccount
{
};

BankAccount BankAccount::MakeSavingAccount()
{
    ...
}

BankAccount BankAccount::MakeChequingAccount()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: How are the factory methods implemented?

Comment: Almost identically to C#. In the 'BankAccount' class.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: The private constructor is trivial in C++ - I just reproduced the C++ code that may not have been obvious.

Comment: Ok - the two parts I thought were trivial are now added.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas What is not obvious is that before C++11 nested classes had no extra access rights to the outer class.

Comment: Your factory methods appear to be slicing.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: I'm not providing an implementation! I don't think these details are what the OP was after - I think the main question was regarding classes nesting their own subclasses.